# MariaDB using all available ram

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

On an computer with 64G of ram I have a mariadb server that uses all available ram even though it is (i think at least) configured to use much less:

```
SHOW VARIABLES

aria_block_size 8192    
aria_checkpoint_interval    30  
aria_checkpoint_log_activity    1048576 
aria_encrypt_tables OFF 
aria_force_start_after_recovery_failures    0   
aria_group_commit   none    
aria_group_commit_interval  0   
aria_log_file_size  1073741824  
aria_log_purge_type immediate   
aria_max_sort_file_size 9223372036853727232 
aria_page_checksum  ON  
aria_pagecache_age_threshold    300 
aria_pagecache_buffer_size  134217728   
aria_pagecache_division_limit   100 
aria_pagecache_file_hash_size   512 
aria_recover    NORMAL  
aria_repair_threads 1   
aria_sort_buffer_size   268434432   
aria_stats_method   nulls_unequal   
aria_sync_log_dir   NEWFILE 
aria_used_for_temp_tables   ON  
auto_increment_increment    1   
auto_increment_offset   1   
autocommit  ON  
automatic_sp_privileges ON  
back_log    152 
basedir /usr    
big_tables  OFF 
binlog_annotate_row_events  OFF 
binlog_cache_size   32768   
binlog_checksum NONE    
binlog_commit_wait_count    0   
binlog_commit_wait_usec 100000  
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF 
binlog_format   STATEMENT   
binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling   ON  
binlog_row_image    FULL    
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768   
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608 
character_set_client    utf8mb4 
character_set_connection    utf8mb4 
character_set_database  utf8mb4 
character_set_filesystem    binary  
character_set_results   utf8mb4 
character_set_server    utf8mb4 
character_set_system    utf8    
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/  
collation_connection    utf8mb4_unicode_ci  
collation_database  utf8mb4_general_ci  
collation_server    utf8mb4_general_ci  
completion_type NO_CHAIN    
concurrent_insert   AUTO    
connect_timeout 10  
core_file   OFF 
datadir /var/lib/mysql/ 
date_format %Y-%m-%d    
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s   
deadlock_search_depth_long  15  
deadlock_search_depth_short 4   
deadlock_timeout_long   50000000    
deadlock_timeout_short  10000   
debug_no_thread_alarm   OFF 
default_master_connection       
default_regex_flags     
default_storage_engine  InnoDB  
default_tmp_storage_engine      
default_week_format 0   
delay_key_write ON  
delayed_insert_limit    100 
delayed_insert_timeout  300 
delayed_queue_size  1000    
div_precision_increment 4   
encrypt_binlog  OFF 
encrypt_tmp_disk_tables OFF 
encrypt_tmp_files   OFF 
enforce_storage_engine      
error_count 0   
event_scheduler OFF 
expensive_subquery_limit    100 
expire_logs_days    10  
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF 
external_user       
extra_max_connections   1   
extra_port  0   
flush   OFF 
flush_time  0   
foreign_key_checks  ON  
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|  
ft_max_word_len 84  
ft_min_word_len 4   
ft_query_expansion_limit    20  
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)  
general_log OFF 
general_log_file    prod4.log   
group_concat_max_len    1024    
gtid_binlog_pos     
gtid_binlog_state       
gtid_current_pos        
gtid_domain_id  0   
gtid_ignore_duplicates  OFF 
gtid_seq_no 0   
gtid_slave_pos      
gtid_strict_mode    OFF 
have_compress   YES 
have_crypt  YES 
have_dynamic_loading    YES 
have_geometry   YES 
have_openssl    NO  
have_profiling  YES 
have_query_cache    YES 
have_rtree_keys YES 
have_ssl    DISABLED    
have_symlink    YES 
histogram_size  0   
histogram_type  SINGLE_PREC_HB  
host_cache_size 628 
hostname    prod4   
identity    0   
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF 
ignore_db_dirs      
in_transaction  0   
init_connect        
init_file       
init_slave      
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON  
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10.000000   
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON  
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions   1   
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000  
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608 
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5   
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF 
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF 
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF 
innodb_api_trx_level    0   
innodb_autoextend_increment 64  
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1   
innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval 3600    
innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed OFF 
innodb_background_scrub_data_interval   604800  
innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed   OFF 
innodb_buf_dump_status_frequency    0   
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 100 
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool  
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8   
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_populate OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_size 12884901888 
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25  
innodb_change_buffering all 
innodb_checksum_algorithm   INNODB  
innodb_checksums    ON  
innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor   HIGH_CHECKPOINT 
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF 
innodb_commit_concurrency   0   
innodb_compression_algorithm    zlib    
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5   
innodb_compression_level    6   
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50  
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000    
innodb_corrupt_table_action assert  
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend  
innodb_data_home_dir        
innodb_default_encryption_key_id    1   
innodb_default_row_format   compact 
innodb_defragment   OFF 
innodb_defragment_fill_factor   0.900000    
innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs    20  
innodb_defragment_frequency 40  
innodb_defragment_n_pages   7   
innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy    0   
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF 
innodb_disallow_writes  OFF 
innodb_doublewrite  ON  
innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm    BACKOFF 
innodb_encrypt_log  OFF 
innodb_encrypt_tables   OFF 
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age    1   
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops 100 
innodb_encryption_threads   0   
innodb_fake_changes OFF 
innodb_fast_shutdown    1   
innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold   600 
innodb_file_format  Antelope    
innodb_file_format_check    ON  
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope    
innodb_file_per_table   ON  
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1   
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  0   
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT    
innodb_flush_neighbors  1   
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30  
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF 
innodb_force_primary_key    OFF 
innodb_force_recovery   0   
innodb_foreground_preflush  EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF 
innodb_ft_aux_table     
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000 
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF 
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON  
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84  
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3   
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000    
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000  
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table     
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2   
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000   
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table       
innodb_idle_flush_pct   100 
innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed    OFF 
innodb_instrument_semaphores    OFF 
innodb_io_capacity  400 
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000    
innodb_kill_idle_transaction    0   
innodb_large_prefix OFF 
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm  fcfs    
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50  
innodb_locking_fake_changes ON  
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF 
innodb_log_arch_dir ./  
innodb_log_arch_expire_sec  0   
innodb_log_archive  OFF 
innodb_log_block_size   512 
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608 
innodb_log_checksum_algorithm   INNODB  
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON  
innodb_log_file_size    1073741824  
innodb_log_files_in_group   2   
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./  
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024    
innodb_max_bitmap_file_size 104857600   
innodb_max_changed_pages    1000000 
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75.000000   
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0.001000    
innodb_max_purge_lag    0   
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0   
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1   
innodb_monitor_disable      
innodb_monitor_enable       
innodb_monitor_reset        
innodb_monitor_reset_all        
innodb_mtflush_threads  8   
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37  
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000    
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728   
innodb_open_files   400 
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF 
innodb_page_size    16384   
innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization    OFF 
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF 
innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info OFF 
innodb_purge_batch_size 300 
innodb_purge_threads    1   
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF 
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56  
innodb_read_io_threads  64  
innodb_read_only    OFF 
innodb_replication_delay    0   
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF 
innodb_rollback_segments    128 
innodb_sched_priority_cleaner   19  
innodb_scrub_log    OFF 
innodb_scrub_log_speed  256 
innodb_show_locks_held  10  
innodb_show_verbose_locks   0   
innodb_simulate_comp_failures   0   
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576 
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6   
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON  
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked  OFF 
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal 
innodb_stats_modified_counter   0   
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF 
innodb_stats_persistent ON  
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20  
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8   
innodb_stats_traditional    ON  
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8   
innodb_status_output    OFF 
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF 
innodb_strict_mode  OFF 
innodb_support_xa   ON  
innodb_sync_array_size  1   
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30  
innodb_table_locks  ON  
innodb_thread_concurrency   0   
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000   
innodb_tmpdir       
innodb_track_changed_pages  OFF 
innodb_undo_directory   .   
innodb_undo_logs    128 
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0   
innodb_use_atomic_writes    OFF 
innodb_use_fallocate    OFF 
innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit   ON  
innodb_use_mtflush  OFF 
innodb_use_native_aio   ON  
innodb_use_stacktrace   OFF 
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON  
innodb_use_trim OFF 
innodb_version  5.6.42-84.2 
innodb_write_io_threads 4   
insert_id   0   
interactive_timeout 28800   
join_buffer_size    262144  
join_buffer_space_limit 2097152 
join_cache_level    2   
keep_files_on_create    OFF 
key_buffer_size 33554432    
key_cache_age_threshold 300 
key_cache_block_size    1024    
key_cache_division_limit    100 
key_cache_file_hash_size    512 
key_cache_segments  0   
large_files_support ON  
large_page_size 0   
large_pages OFF 
last_gtid       
last_insert_id  0   
lc_messages en_US   
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql    
lc_time_names   en_US   
license GPL 
local_infile    ON  
lock_wait_timeout   31536000    
locked_in_memory    OFF 
log_bin OFF 
log_bin_basename        
log_bin_index       
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF 
log_error   /var/log/mysql/error.log    
log_output  FILE    
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF 
log_slave_updates   OFF 
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF 
log_slow_filter admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_sca...   
log_slow_rate_limit 1   
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF 
log_slow_verbosity      
log_tc_size 24576   
log_warnings    1   
long_query_time 10.000000   
low_priority_updates    OFF 
lower_case_file_system  OFF 
lower_case_table_names  0   
master_verify_checksum  OFF 
max_allowed_packet  16777216    
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520    
max_binlog_size 104857600   
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520    
max_connect_errors  100 
max_connections 512 
max_delayed_threads 20  
max_digest_length   1024    
max_error_count 64  
max_heap_table_size 16777216    
max_insert_delayed_threads  20  
max_join_size   18446744073709551615    
max_length_for_sort_data    1024    
max_long_data_size  16777216    
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382   
max_relay_log_size  104857600   
max_seeks_for_key   4294967295  
max_session_mem_used    9223372036854775807 
max_sort_length 1024    
max_sp_recursion_depth  0   
max_statement_time  0.000000    
max_tmp_tables  32  
max_user_connections    0   
max_write_lock_count    4294967295  
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024    
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8   
min_examined_row_limit  0   
mrr_buffer_size 262144  
multi_range_count   256 
myisam_block_size   1024    
myisam_data_pointer_size    6   
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232 
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615    
myisam_recover_options  BACKUP  
myisam_repair_threads   1   
myisam_sort_buffer_size 134216704   
myisam_stats_method NULLS_UNEQUAL   
myisam_use_mmap OFF 
mysql56_temporal_format ON  
net_buffer_length   16384   
net_read_timeout    30  
net_retry_count 10  
net_write_timeout   60  
old OFF 
old_alter_table OFF 
old_mode        
old_passwords   OFF 
open_files_limit    8551    
optimizer_prune_level   1   
optimizer_search_depth  62  
optimizer_selectivity_sampling_limit    100 
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_so...   
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity 1   
performance_schema  ON  
performance_schema_accounts_size    100 
performance_schema_digests_size 10000   
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000   
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10  
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_...   10000   
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10  
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000   
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10  
performance_schema_hosts_size   100 
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80  
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   3348    
performance_schema_max_digest_length    1024    
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50  
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768   
performance_schema_max_file_instances   3077    
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200 
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  10072   
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   40  
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 5024    
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10  
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 1044    
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150 
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    178 
performance_schema_max_table_handles    4000    
performance_schema_max_table_instances  12500   
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50  
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 1124    
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512 
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100 
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100 
performance_schema_users_size   100 
pid_file    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid  
plugin_dir  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/ 
plugin_maturity unknown 
port    3306    
preload_buffer_size 32768   
profiling   OFF 
profiling_history_size  15  
progress_report_time    5   
protocol_version    10  
proxy_user      
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF 
pseudo_thread_id    16370   
query_alloc_block_size  16384   
query_cache_limit   16777216    
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096    
query_cache_size    0   
query_cache_strip_comments  OFF 
query_cache_type    OFF 
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF 
query_prealloc_size 24576   
rand_seed1  357956615   
rand_seed2  975103936   
range_alloc_block_size  4096    
read_buffer_size    131072  
read_only   OFF 
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144  
relay_log       
relay_log_basename      
relay_log_index     
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info  
relay_log_purge ON  
relay_log_recovery  OFF 
relay_log_space_limit   0   
replicate_annotate_row_events   OFF 
replicate_do_db     
replicate_do_table      
replicate_events_marked_for_skip    REPLICATE   
replicate_ignore_db     
replicate_ignore_table      
replicate_wild_do_table     
replicate_wild_ignore_table     
report_host     
report_password     
report_port 3306    
report_user     
rowid_merge_buff_size   8388608 
secure_auth ON  
secure_file_priv        
server_id   0   
skip_external_locking   ON  
skip_name_resolve   OFF 
skip_networking OFF 
skip_parallel_replication   OFF 
skip_replication    OFF 
skip_show_database  OFF 
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF 
slave_ddl_exec_mode IDEMPOTENT  
slave_domain_parallel_threads   0   
slave_exec_mode STRICT  
slave_load_tmpdir   /tmp    
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824  
slave_net_timeout   3600    
slave_parallel_max_queued   131072  
slave_parallel_mode conservative    
slave_parallel_threads  0   
slave_run_triggers_for_rbr  NO  
slave_skip_errors   OFF 
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON  
slave_transaction_retries   10  
slave_type_conversions      
slow_launch_time    2   
slow_query_log  OFF 
slow_query_log_file prod4-slow.log  
socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
sort_buffer_size    2097152 
sql_auto_is_null    OFF 
sql_big_selects ON  
sql_buffer_result   OFF 
sql_log_bin ON  
sql_log_off OFF 
sql_mode    NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION  
sql_notes   ON  
sql_quote_show_create   ON  
sql_safe_updates    OFF 
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615    
sql_slave_skip_counter  0   
sql_warnings    OFF 
ssl_ca      
ssl_capath      
ssl_cert        
ssl_cipher      
ssl_crl     
ssl_crlpath     
ssl_key     
storage_engine  InnoDB  
stored_program_cache    256 
strict_password_validation  ON  
sync_binlog 0   
sync_frm    ON  
sync_master_info    10000   
sync_relay_log  10000   
sync_relay_log_info 10000   
system_time_zone    UTC 
table_definition_cache  400 
table_open_cache    4000    
thread_cache_size   8   
thread_concurrency  10  
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection   
thread_pool_idle_timeout    60  
thread_pool_max_threads 1000    
thread_pool_oversubscribe   3   
thread_pool_size    8   
thread_pool_stall_limit 500 
thread_stack    196608  
time_format %H:%i:%s    
time_zone   SYSTEM  
timed_mutexes   OFF 
timestamp   1561288673.757972   
tmp_table_size  16777216    
tmpdir  /tmp    
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192    
transaction_prealloc_size   4096    
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ 
tx_read_only    OFF 
unique_checks   ON  
updatable_views_with_limit  YES 
use_stat_tables NEVER   
userstat    OFF 
version 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.10.2    
version_comment Ubuntu 18.10    
version_compile_machine x86_64  
version_compile_os  debian-linux-gnu    
version_malloc_library  system jemalloc 
version_ssl_library YaSSL 2.4.4 
wait_timeout    28800   
warning_count   0   
wsrep_osu_method    TOI 
wsrep_auto_increment_control    ON  
wsrep_causal_reads  OFF 
wsrep_certification_rules   strict  
wsrep_certify_nonpk ON  
wsrep_cluster_address       
wsrep_cluster_name  my_wsrep_cluster    
wsrep_convert_lock_to_trx   OFF 
wsrep_data_home_dir /var/lib/mysql/ 
wsrep_dbug_option       
wsrep_debug OFF 
wsrep_desync    OFF 
wsrep_dirty_reads   OFF 
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround  OFF 
wsrep_forced_binlog_format  NONE    
wsrep_gtid_domain_id    0   
wsrep_gtid_mode OFF 
wsrep_load_data_splitting   ON  
wsrep_log_conflicts OFF 
wsrep_max_ws_rows   0   
wsrep_max_ws_size   2147483647  
wsrep_mysql_replication_bundle  0   
wsrep_node_address      
wsrep_node_incoming_address AUTO    
wsrep_node_name prod4   
wsrep_notify_cmd        
wsrep_on    OFF 
wsrep_patch_version wsrep_25.24 
wsrep_provider  none    
wsrep_provider_options      
wsrep_recover   OFF 
wsrep_reject_queries    NONE    
wsrep_replicate_myisam  OFF 
wsrep_restart_slave OFF 
wsrep_retry_autocommit  1   
wsrep_slave_fk_checks   ON  
wsrep_slave_uk_checks   OFF 
wsrep_slave_threads 1   
wsrep_sst_auth      
wsrep_sst_donor     
wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries OFF 
wsrep_sst_method    rsync   
wsrep_sst_receive_address   AUTO    
wsrep_start_position    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 
wsrep_sync_wait 0
```

Output of tuning-primer also seems fine:

```
INNODB STATUS
Current InnoDB index space = 42.05 G
Current InnoDB data space = 48.17 G
Current InnoDB buffer pool free = 40 %
Current innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12.00 G
Depending on how much space your innodb indexes take up it may be safe
to increase this value to up to 2 / 3 of total system memory

MEMORY USAGE
Max Memory Ever Allocated : 12.16 G
Configured Max Per-thread Buffers : 1.40 G
Configured Max Global Buffers : 12.04 G
Configured Max Memory Limit : 13.45 G
Physical Memory : 62.79 G
Max memory limit seem to be within acceptable norms
```

After a few hours the output of top look like this:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
26350 mysql     20   0   64.3g  55.3g  19300 S  29.9  88.0 354:20.10 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

shortly after this oom_reaper would kill mysql:

```
[3308788.693609] Out of memory: Kill process 30421 (mysqld) score 915 or sacrifice child
[3308788.693727] Killed process 30421 (mysqld) total-vm:78894468kB, anon-rss:64508740kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[3308790.493095] oom_reaper: reaped process 30421 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Im using 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.10.2 on ubuntu 18.10

Pretty much all of the table are innodb, result from show global status is here: https://pastebin.com/7ayJBpgC

New settings, after changing some settings as Rick James suggested:
https://pastebin.com/N55AzWFw

Comment: Nothing obvious.  Could you also provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.  What Engine is being used by your tables?

Comment: Any idea of what queries were run shortly before the OOM?

Comment: I have added result of show global status (while mysql is consuming ~48g of ram) to the original post, not sure which queries are running when it gets killed, but since all the queries finish pretty fast and the usage ramps slowly (it takes ~12 hours to fill all available ram) it probably doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Rick James suggesting that some default settings are weird I decided to upgrade to official (1:10.2.25+maria~cosmic) instead of ubuntu distributed packages and the memory problem seems to have gone away without any changes to config.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 2736 mysql     20   0   27.4g  15.0g  22624 S 141.7  23.9 384:24.58 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

current variables: https://pastebin.com/7C96E6J4

current status: https://pastebin.com/G55ydpJy

Additional data as requested by Wilson Hauck:

we are using 2x Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB in raid 1 on on an i7-6700K

```
iostat -xm 5 3:

Linux 4.18.0-20-generic (prod4)     07/04/2019  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           7.10    0.08    1.43    1.53    0.00   89.86

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sdb              6.35  205.97      0.41      4.21     1.79    63.35  21.94  23.52    0.33    1.85   0.67    66.31    20.92   1.19  25.22
sda             14.63  205.95      0.70      4.17     2.58    62.76  14.98  23.36    0.19    1.43   0.58    48.67    20.73   1.06  23.46
md0              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     3.47   489.75   0.00   0.00
md2             19.86  232.03      0.84      4.23     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00    43.43    18.65   0.00   0.00
md1              1.33    2.51      0.01      0.01     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     4.00     4.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           9.38    0.00    1.61    2.18    0.00   86.83

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sdb              0.00  352.80      0.00      6.88     0.00    57.60   0.00  14.04    0.00    0.26   0.40     0.00    19.97   0.88  31.12
sda              0.00  353.00      0.00      6.88     0.00    57.40   0.00  13.99    0.00    0.26   0.39     0.00    19.96   0.86  30.48
md0              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
md2              0.00  370.80      0.00      6.87     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    18.98   0.00   0.00
md1              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.00    0.00    1.69    2.16    0.00   88.14

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sdb              0.00  387.60      0.00      7.49     0.00    76.20   0.00  16.43    0.00    0.24   0.42     0.00    19.78   0.83  32.16
sda              0.00  387.60      0.00      7.49     0.00    76.20   0.00  16.43    0.00    0.31   0.42     0.00    19.78   0.82  31.60
md0              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
md2              0.00  422.20      0.00      7.48     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00    18.15   0.00   0.00
md1              0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: v 10.2.25 has worked in your favor. Thanks for current variables and status.  Do you have SSD or rotating HDD?  Also could you post TEXT results from LX Command Prompt of iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count?

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES.  Alas, nothing clearly points to why you are having that Memory problem.

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.10.2
- 64 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 10:28:11; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

`thread_cache_size` -- Increase to 50.

`long_query_time = 1` and turn on the slowlog.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog  There are multiple signs of queries that may need improving -- perhaps better indexing, perhaps better formulation.  The slowlog will help us locate which ones to focus on.

Is this server part of a Galera cluster?  I may have further questions or comments depending on the answer.

`Max_used_connections` reached 199.  This is rather high.  Hopefully tackling the slow queries will bring this down.

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) / _ram ) = (32M / 0.20 + 12288M / 0.70) / 65536M = 27.0%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( table_open_cache ) = 4,000` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- 700 might be good in your case.  (`Open_tables = 535`)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_os_log_written ) = 8,213,856,256 / 37691 = 217926 /sec` -- This is an indicator of how busy InnoDB is.
-- Very busy InnoDB.

`( Innodb_rows_deleted / Innodb_rows_inserted ) = 1,085,550 / 1658210 = 0.655` -- Churn
-- "Don't queue it, just do it." (If MySQL is being used as a queue.)

`( Innodb_row_lock_waits ) = 9,462 / 37691 = 0.25 /sec` -- How often there is a delay in getting a row lock.
-- May be caused by complex queries that could be optimized.

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster.

`( innodb_thread_concurrency ) = 0` -- 0 = Let InnoDB decide the best for concurrency_tickets.
-- Set to 0 or 64. This may cut back on CPU.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 100,172 / 37691 = 2.7 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size.
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Select_full_join ) = 228,142 / 37691 = 6.1 /sec` -- joins without index
-- Add suitable index(es) to tables used in JOINs.

`( Select_scan ) = 451,720 / 37691 = 12 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 451,720 / 4944883 = 9.1%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Sort_merge_passes ) = 7,711 / 37691 = 0.2 /sec` -- Heafty sorts
-- Increase sort_buffer_size and/or optimize complex queries.

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (2323860 + 36898 + 0 + 0 + 2307510 + 3) / 37691 = 123 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = STATEMENT` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED. ROW is preferred; it may become the default.

`( wsrep_on ) = wsrep_on = OFF` -- Galera: Turn on Replication
-- Why is it OFF?

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".

`( wsrep_log_conflicts ) = wsrep_log_conflicts = OFF` -- If you get deadlock conflicts during COMMIT, this flag can be helpful.

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Connections ) = 619,511 / 37691 = 16 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout; use pooling?

`( Threads_created / Connections ) = 17,071 / 619511 = 2.8%` -- Rapidity of process creation
`( thread_cache_size / max_connections ) = 8 / 512 = 1.6%`
-- Increase thread_cache_size (non-Windows)

**Abnormally small:**

```
Acl_database_grants = 3
Acl_users = 5
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused = 13,617
Innodb_background_log_sync = 36,995
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 0.20%
Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops = 512
Memory_used = 179.5MB
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Aria_pagecache_write_requests = 682 /sec
Aria_pagecache_writes = 270 /sec
Aria_transaction_log_syncs = 1,238
Com_show_binlogs = 12 /HR
Com_show_engine_status = 83 /HR
Com_show_plugins = 83 /HR
Feature_locale = 3.1 /HR
Handler_delete = 74 /sec
Handler_discover = 5 /HR
Handler_icp_attempts = 60233 /sec
Handler_icp_match = 59945 /sec
Handler_tmp_update = 5583 /sec
Handler_tmp_write = 11043 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 296959 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty = 61,297
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests = 5262 /sec
Innodb_ibuf_merged_deletes = 0.32 /sec
Innodb_rows_updated = 358 /sec
Rows_tmp_read = 7844 /sec
Select_range = 59 /sec
Select_range / Com_select = 44.7%
Sort_rows = 9375 /sec
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
Update_scan = 123,123
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
max_relay_log_size = 100MB
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
innodb_default_row_format = compact
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
```

**Changes made by OP**

```
innodb_flush_neighbors  1     | innodb_flush_neighbors  0
long_query_time 10.000000     | long_query_time 1.000000
open_files_limit    8551      | open_files_limit    2565
pseudo_thread_id    16370     | pseudo_thread_id    32010
rand_seed1  357956615         | rand_seed1  386239716
rand_seed2  975103936         | rand_seed2  465882405
slow_query_log  OFF           | slow_query_log  ON  
slow_query_log_file prod4-slo | slow_query_log_file /var/
table_open_cache    4000      | table_open_cache    700
thread_cache_size   8         | thread_cache_size   50
timestamp   1561288673.757972 | timestamp   1561333380.04
```

Comment: Thank you! I have enabled slowlog and changed some of the settings, and made it so that some slow queries are more infrequent, new settings are here:
https://pastebin.com/N55AzWFw

also, this server is not part of a galera cluster

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second=RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=256  # from 50 per 10.n.nn MaridDB refman minimum
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 400 to enable higher SSD IOPS
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G  # from 12G to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 14
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 61,297
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned on my profile, Network profile where we have free Utility Scripts to improve performance and additional suggestions.